# Does the Book of Ryu lock rewards if you don't max it before the next volume starts?

Tags: .hack-gu-last-recode

In the original *.hack//G.U* the Books of Ryu had unlockable rewards like Wallpapers and BGMs for the in-game desktop, like that of the original *.hack* games.

like the original *.hack* Games when you beat one Volume you could then import your save data into the next Volume retaining items, levels and Book of Ryu Progress and rewards. But in G.U if you didn't get all of the rewards from the Book of Ryu for that volume and in the next volume unlocked that reward you'd get a cash reward rather than the normal unlock, this would continue until the Book of Ryu's progress had caught up to where it would be had it have been maxed out in the previous volume

When i played the original *.hack//G.U* i would continue playing a volume after beating it's final boss (ie. Azure Flame God) maxing the progress of all Book of Ryu before moving onto the next volume. but with *.hack//G.U Last Recode* all 3 Chapters are in the 1 game (as they so advertised).

So i am wondering, Does the Book of Ryu lock rewards if you progress too far? ie. i beat Azure Flame God for Volume 1 *Rebirth* and move into Volume 2 *Reminisce*?

Answer (score -1):

It locks the books at 3 in the first volume, but anything you've done extra carry over into the second volume.
Example... book 8 is based around bikes, I maxed it out at 3 in the first volume, when I converted it over to volume 2 the book 8 went up to 5

Comment: I have fixed up the question title which I think caused your confusion. I know about maxing the books but I was talking about if you don't max them before the next volume starts